# Rredis RPush with Node js

Tags: node.js, redis

i want to add items to an array using redis and RPush, but i revceived an error :

**Code**

```
 const redis = require('redis');
const redisClient = redis.createClient();

     var arr = ["some val","some val2","some val3"];
            
            var multi = redisClient.multi();
        
            for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                
                multi.rpush('veggies', arr[i]);
                
            }
        
            multi.exec(function(err, response) {
                if(err) throw err; 
                console.log("response : ", response);
            })
```

**Error**

```
WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

How can i resolve this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This error is from the redis-server itself, and it means that the type of the value stored in `veggies` is not a `list`. You can use the [`TYPE`](https://redis.io/commands/type) command to check what is the type of the value stored at a certain key.

```
TYPE veggies
```

Comment: The type is string, and i am pushig strings, but the error persist

Comment: I receive also this error when i try "get veggies2"

Comment: The type is "string", therefore you can't use `RPUSH`, which only operates on lists. Regarding "veggies2" - the GET command only works on strings, I guess that the value at "veggies2" is not a string.